# Win7 -> Ubuntu on Media Server w/ Multiple Drives Help

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I currently have a Windows 7 PC built to run Plex Media Server. The current configuration is I have Windows 7 installed on a SSD Primary boot drive, and all my media is stored on a secondary HDD.

I would like to change OS from Win7 to Ubuntu, but I have nearly 1.5 TB of content that I don't have any way of storing. So, my primary question(s) are:

1. If I install Ubuntu on my primary SSD boot drive, will my secondary HDD be untouched?
2. If I perform the action outlined in question #1 and the secondary HDD is intact, will Ubuntu be able to read the content on the HDD currently without a reformat?

Ultimately, in a perfect world, I could install Ubuntu on the main drive and my secondary drive would just exist without being modified and work just as it does on Win7. However, I'm pretty sure that perfect doesn't exist. Yes I'm a pessimist :P

Comment: The HDD can't be touched if you disconnect the cable to the HDD before you install Ubuntu. After you install Ubuntu and reconnect the cable to the HDD, Ubuntu will be able to read the content on the HDD without a reformat.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted this leaving the NTFS file system in place, but ultimately decided to reformat to ext4 and do a fresh install of Ubuntu in place of Win7 for this machine. It worked fine with the NTFS, but I felt any future troubleshooting would be easier using the ext4 file system.